# Why does my video uploaded to iPhone Photos to OneDrive lack vibrancy when viewed on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, video, onedrive

After uploading a video from iPhone Photos to OneDrive I noticed the vibrancy of the video had substantially changed (e.g. greens were substantially less green, blues less blue).
While I would expect a change when viewed on a different device eg PC via Windows, I would not expect a change when viewing the same content on the same iPhone device via the OneDrive app.

Why is this happening?

Background:
For those who might wonder why I'm doing this, it is because the content is rarely accessed and I want to free up some iCloud space.

OK, I think I've got a major part of the explanation.
My original upload was done without setting Options>"All Photos Data" before sharing.

I have checked with [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download).

When exported with "All Photos Data" set, it seems to have been converted to:

- AVC instead of using HVC1 codec
- Has dropped Dolby Vision
- Has dropped from 10bits to 8bits bit depth

It looks much closer to the original now, however, it still looks a bit lower brightness when opened in OneDrive.

On my Windows machine, it looks much closer to the original also, but I realise I have sacrificed efficiency and some bit depth of the original.

Comment: What happens if you add that video back to Photos.app? Maybe OneDrive media player does not handle EDR (or something else).

Comment: Thanks @MateuszSzlosek. 
Yes, I have exported back to Photos app and it looks fine now. It is a HDR video, so I can only assume that OneDrive doesn't support HDR and/or HEVC encoded videos to the full extent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem for this is with OneDrive and Windows (which also loses depth when viewed in native applications).

More info:

- [HDR Headaches when your phone supports HDR but your system doesn't](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/80939-hdr-headaches-when-your-iphone-supports-hdr-but-your-system-doesnt/)
- [Differences and why it might not matter](https://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-record-Dolby-Vision-HDR-video-iPhone-12Pro-compatibility-YouTube_id128208#:%7E:text=)

Confusingly I feel users such as myself think that the "*All Photos Data*" option uploads the native original copy (ie the most optimum settings and metadata) whereas in this circumstance it seems to downgrade the content to a lower common denominator (ie a lesser codec that can be viewed by more).